# Find Azure resource group by Vm name

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group, azure-node-sdk

I am trying to find the resource group allocated to a VM in azure using nodejs.

I am using the below link as my reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/resource-manager-node-resources-and-groups/resource-manager-node-resources-and-groups/#list-groups

The below gets resource group details If I provide `resourceGroupName and subscription_Id`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resource-groups/get

But I only have `VM name and subsciption_Id`

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/compute-node-manage-vm/compute-node-manage-vm/

This shows an example where you can list all VMs in a subsription.

```
 computeClient.virtualMachines.listAll(function (err, result)
```

The will result in the VM ID which will have the RG name in it (**TESTRG9397** in this example).

```
id: '/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/TESTRG9397/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm3365'
```

You will have to parse the ID to get it but then you will have RG and SUB so you can call

```
computeClient.virtualMachines.get(resourceGroupName, vmName, function (err, result))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this totally makes sense. But If I have of thousands of VM's listing all and parsing resource ID from that might not be an optimal case. 
I see python3 provides a direct function called ```get_rg_of_vm(vm_name)```, Sad that node doesn't have one like that

Comment: And this is a potential roadblock https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931327/azure-node-sdk-to-get-more-than-50-virtual-machines